# how to select the currentRow again after iterator.excuteQuery() in adf?

Tags: java, oracle-adf

i have ADF page that has update method , and after the update the table is refreshed , all of this business is done in the backing bean and here is the code

```
OperationBinding operationBinding =  ADFUtil.getBindingContainer().getOperationBinding("manageRequestStatus"); // this is the update method

Object result = operationBinding.execute();
```

after the update is executed the value is changed in the DB so i call this in order to refresh the adf table

```
DCIteratorBinding searchIterator = ADFUtil.findIterator("myIterator");
searchIterator.executeQuery();
```

this method to refresh the dataTable and the table is refreshed with the new data

the problem is : after executeQuery the first Row of the table is selected

what i want to do is : after refresh , select the same row

and this is my try :

```
RowSetIterator rsi = searchIterator.getRowSetIterator();
 Row currentRow = rsi.getCurrentRow();
 Key k =currentRow.getKey();
searchIterator.executeQuery();
rsi.setCurrentRow(currentRow) ;
```

Comment: is your selectionEvent on your jsf table as follow : selectionListener="#{bindings.YOURVO.collectionModel.makeCurrent}" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've solved this problem by following

```
Int index =searchIterator.getCurrentRowIndexInRange();
searchIterator.executeQuery();
searchIterator.setCurrentRowIndexInRange(index);
```